# Google App Engine Deployment Failed, "empty index configuration"

Tags: git, google-app-engine, git-push, git-remote

I've been trying to push my local copy to the remote repository. However, the following error shows up on my console:

```
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Deploying...
remote: Created deployment: uconnect-dev-server.clouddev.gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d.deployment_1382264909584
remote: Created deployment: uconnect-dev-server.clouddev.gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d.deployment_1382264909584
remote: Created deployment: uconnect-dev-server.clouddev.gaeTemplate-d981b975f1ecaa6d.deployment_1382264909584
remote: Deployment failed: Deployment failed, details: { Failed to load application, Empty index configuration., none}
To https://code.google.com/id/-i5ivOq1gug/
   fe3d360..51bda59  dev -> master
```

The same issue also happens when I use master -> master. What "index configuration" is being referred to here? I've already done the commit locally and the push to the remote server is the only issue.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What language is this app running? GAE apps have an optional 'datastore index configuration file' ([python](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/indexconfig), [java](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/indexconfig)). If you have an empty index file, GAE throws this error during deployment. (Git has nothing to do with this error by the way. This is strictly a GAE issue). If you don't need a datastore index, delete the the index.yaml/datastore-indexes.xml file completely. This might solve your issue.

Comment: it's in python, and it worked! thank you very much! I changed the title of this post to make it more accurate.