# Google push-to-deploy: Deployment FAILED

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine, deployment

I did set up a Release Pipeline in Google Developers Console. The Pipeline shall monitor a Code repository hosted at google and deploy source only (Python).

I can deploy the application manually using Google App Engine SDK, but the automated deployment fails:

```
Deployment failed. Details: Deployment failed, details: { Failed to load application, Empty index configuration., none}
```

I do have got a proper app.yaml and index.yaml file in the / folder of the master branch.

- Is there anything else I have to take care of?
- Could it be that I should not mix push-to-deploy and manual deployment?
- Is there a way to get a more verbose output?

Cheers
-Luca.

Answer (score 0):

I had to delete the index.yaml file, as described in [Google App Engine Deployment Failed, "empty index configuration"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476417/google-app-engine-deployment-failed-empty-index-configuration)

The index.yaml file looked ok to me, it was not empty at all, but it didn't contain any index definition.

Cheers
-Luca.